# java.lang.LinkageError: loading constraint violation when overriding method "org/w3c/dom/Node.setUserData

Tags: java, soap

I'm trying to call webservice but I'm getting the bellow response:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <soapenv:Fault>
         <faultcode>soapenv:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring>java.lang.LinkageError: loading constraint violation when overriding method "org/w3c/dom/Node.setUserData(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;Lorg/w3c/dom/UserDataHandler;)Ljava/lang/Object;" during creation of class "com/ibm/ws/webservices/engine/xmlsoap/SOAPPart": loader "org/eclipse/osgi/internal/baseadaptor/DefaultClassLoader@6d776858" of class "com/ibm/ws/webservices/engine/xmlsoap/SOAPPart" and loader "com/ibm/oti/vm/BootstrapClassLoader@7d4883b2" of class "org/w3c/dom/Node" have different types for the method signature</faultstring>
         <detail/>
      </soapenv:Fault>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I'm updating the application from java 6 to java 8, websphere 8.0 to 9.0.3, on the lower versions everything works fine but after the update this part doesn't want to work.

The above error I get it only the first time I call the endpoint after the application started, the rest of the time I get:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <soapenv:Fault>
         <faultcode>soapenv:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring>java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/ibm/ws/webservices/engine/SOAPPart</faultstring>
         <detail/>
      </soapenv:Fault>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The classloading policy is **Classes loaded with local class loader first (parent last)**

I don't know what else to try, the depedency is declared in the main pom like bellow:

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>com.ibm.websphere.ws</groupId>
     <artifactId>runtime</artifactId>
     <version>9.0.0</version>
     <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

And use it in the modules I need like bellow:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ibm.websphere.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>runtime</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I don't know what else to do....